# Make connection to another PC for SQL transactions

Tags: sql, connection

I want my connection to work in any PC not just my computer, How can I do that ?
this is my connection statement :

```
SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\toshiba\Desktop\New folder (6)\SBMS\App_Data\SBMSDB.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True; MultipleActiveResultSets=True");
```

Comment: You'll need to change the `AttachDbFilename` property to a relative path.

Comment: which programming language you are using ?

Comment: @ A5l-lE5 ,I'm using sql with c#

Answer (score 0):

In data source, pass IP/Name of Server on which SQL server is running.
    Data Source=221.135.137.146

Answer (score 0):

try this :-

```
con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://IP address:port for mysql/DB name?zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull","username","password");
```